# Thermometer type in electrical water heater

Tags: arduino, temperature, hardware, home-automation, water

I'm working on my home monitoring system and already succeed with electricity consumption measurement and got closer to water system.

Measuring water consumption is almost solved, but as we are using **boiler** almost 365 days a year I would like to **measure water temperature in a tank** as well to have more info on it.

As the tank itself is tightly isolated I've got an idea to intrude into boiler and use it's temperature sensor.

Water heater has electronic (*buttons*) control (model *ARISTON VELIS 50*)

[image: Water heater electronic control panel]

Under the hood it looks like this (*2 tanks*)

[image: Boiler under the hood]

And temperature sensor for this model is the following

[image: Temperature sensor]

As it seen on the picture the left thermostat has **3 wires** which I suppose are:

- GND
- VCC
- DATA

whereas the right tank has kinda 4 wires going out the same place.

I'm wondering:

- if its possible to know how to **read the temperature data from 3 wires sensor** or how to know the "protocol" its using for data transmission?
- is it possible to **intercept this data** not interfering with the boiler board?

Maybe there are some traditional/known approaches for such kind of tasks or this is regular temperature sensor, but I don't have a clue what to start with bec. organizing a workspace under the boiler not knowing what to do is quite uncomfortable.

> Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope to read raw signal, but I have both *Arduino* and *RaspberryPi3* and *multimiter* in my arsenal.

Comment: Can you find any datasheets or other information on the sensor?

Comment: That electronics does not look like it has isolation from mains. Do not mess with it, mains voltage is lethal.

Comment: Is the yellow wire labeled `DATA`?  Or is it your guess that the signal is digital?  Or did you observe the signal with an oscilloscope and saw that it's digital?  [In the meantime, I'd like to second @TurboJ 's point about isolation from mains.]

Comment: @Turbo J If the OP has already created an electrical consumption measurement system, I think its pretty reasonable to assume they are familiar with how to handle mains power. There is no need to warn them of the dangers of it, or warn them off.

Comment: It is just your opinion about Vcc, Gnd, Data? Try to make a close picture of PCB, then it might turn out what sensor it is.

Comment: @TurboJ I understand, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Normally a DMM with Vdc Vac can tell you if it is analog or digital, expect the middle (Y) to be the sensor signal. Are there not 2 heaters and sensors?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thats actually only my guess about pinout and digital signal. I presumed that signal is digital bec. of 3 wires, but can mistake.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, thanks for warning. In the comment above I mentioned that I only presumed the signal is digital as it has 3 wires. Yet I observed no labels bec. didn't go very deep into unless I have some strategy/overview. And I have no option for signal observation besides DMM.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, there are 2 heaters and (_I suppose_) 2 sensors. The second heater is ON when _FAST_ button is pressed.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum, the only info I found on this sensor is catalogue number what gave me only info on where to buy. Unfortunately no datasheet or any clue on sensor type.

Comment: Not sure why you want to measure temp when it is displayed.  Are you expecting more cost with higher T? , that gives more capacity but shorter life of tank.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, the temp is displayed very approx. +-10 degrees. The reason for its measuring for me is already a matter of principle as I want to integrate more of regular house hardware into home monitoring system and be able to monitor it remotely.

Comment: I will perform a test with DMM on detecting what type of signal is there observing all precautions and those that were mentioned here as well.

Comment: After much searching through the site mentioned in the image (A LINK WOULD HAVE BEEN NICE!!!) I finally found the page for it. There's a magic word in the name of it: "ARISTON sensor ***NTC*** VELIS 1500W" which tells me it's a Negative Temperature Coefficient thermistor. It may be wired as a half-bridge wheatstone.

Comment: Also they're nice and cheap. I'd suggest buying one to experiment with rather than risk blowing up your boiler. You could also examine it in more detail and even dismantle it.

Comment: @Majenko, thanks a lot. I should read better next time I probably was so involved in finding something concrete that missed what was somewhere around. I think an answer from you would be nice to accept on this question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that @TurboJ is correct that there is no galvanic isolation. That would make the signals very difficult to deal with safely- the sensor appears to be tied to one side of the mains.

As it's clearly (well, after the good research done by user222030 and Majenko) some kind of dual NTC resistance probe it will be very nonlinear and referenced to some voltage such as 3.3V or 5V on the board. You would have to reverse engineer the circuit and then you'd still have an nonlinear nasty voltage connected to one side of the mains, ready to blow the living **** out of your home automation system, damage the boiler controls, or electrocute the hapless user.

While you **could** attempt to introduce another sensor into one of the protection tubes it would have to be insulated sufficiently for the mains to be safe.. which may be non-trivial and I don't think it would be responsible to try to make suggestions remotely on how to do that.

Comment: I started thinking the same about intruding in circuitry after closer analysis. Good catch on adding additional probe inside existing well, didn't think about it actually. Not sure I will try it, but smth. to keep in mind for the future. Also likely non-linearity is what actually stopped me bec. I'm not sure I will be able to handle it correctly. What I will probably stop with is determine the characteristics of NTCs to call it a day. The efficiency I wanted to calculate basing on temperature can be calculated indirectly (_not precise_) and I will probably do it this way. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

From your photo it appears that each sensor is inserted into a closed-ended tube that projects into the boiler, also known as a 'thermopocket' or 'thermowell'.

Depending on the size and shape of the thermowell, you may be able to insert your own sensor into it alongside the existing one. Because the boiler electronics are not isolated from mains, you then need to use **isolated signal conditioning** to measure the temperature from the sensor and transmit it to your home monitoring system. A type J or K thermocouple would be a reasonable choice of sensor: you could get better accuracy with a platinum RTD but you don't need it for this application and it'd cost more.

You could measure this with an [analogue transmitter](https://www.tcdirect.co.uk/Default.aspx?level=2&department_id=250/3), which typically converts the output to a 4 - 20mA current signal. Typically these are loop-powered: you connect the device like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1wfke.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where the 'meter' could be a resistor across which you measure the voltage. \$V_{supply}\$ needs to be enough for the minimum voltage requirement of the transmitter plus the maximum voltage burden of the meter. Or you could use a [data acquisition device](https://www.advantech.com/products/gf-5vtd/adam-4018/mod_da2b87d9-b18d-43bc-b0ef-291c7e1234e4) from which you would read the measurements digitally - the type I've linked uses an RS-485 bus connection (and 'clones' of this type are widely available from different manufacturers) but you may be able to find other types.

As [another answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/438575/2750) notes, there are some **important safety considerations** here:

- you must make sure that your temperature sensor doesn't electrically contact or interfere with the existing sensor
- you must treat anything that could come into electrical contact with the boiler electronics, even by accident, as mains voltage wiring
- you must satisfy yourself that any signal conditioning unit is suitable for your purpose - the ones I've linked to are examples of what is available and not necessarily a recommendation
- you must make sure you understand what is isolated from what by the signal conditioning unit, for example is the power supply connection on the input side of the isolation or the output side

If you are unsure about any of those, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out AT and ADAM-type devices. Now I know few more devices. Also thanks for pointing out all considerations. I indeed stopped thinking about tinkering into the boiler circuitry as it will definitely make it unreliable and it doesn't worth that for sure.

Answer (score 1):

No. Those aren't digital sensors.
Those are two NTC resistors, with a common lead.
I have somewhere resistance/temperature table. I can try to find it if you still need it.

Comment: Would be very nice if you could find such data as it would give me possibility to compare smth. against. I paused this project quite a while ago, but will continue on any new solution/data I will gather. Appreciate your help.